# flask db migrate not detecting Schema from models folder

Tags: python, flask, database-design, sqlalchemy, architecture

Hi guys i am trying to implement MVC pattern in my flask rest API application but I am facing some issues like flask migration and writing scalable code.

For flask migration I'm not able to detect models while migrating to mysql.

Following is my sample app architecture

[image]

This is the models/**ini**.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

And this is my models/user_master.py

```
import dataclasses

import flask_bcrypt
from . import db


# from sqlalchemy_utils import PhoneNumber
@dataclasses
class UserTypeMaster(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'UserTypeMaster'

    def __init__(self, _id, _type):
        self.id = _id
        self.type = _type

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

This is my centuryApi.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate

from config import config_names
from models import db
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from routes.user_route import user_bp

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config_names['default'])
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

db.init_app(app)

migrate = Migrate()
migrate.init_app(app, db)
from models.user_master import UserMaster
from models.address_master import CityMaster, StateMaster, CountryMaster

app.register_blueprint(user_bp, url_prefix='/users')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And if I don't include models after initializing migrate object and run flask db migrate I get following:

> INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
> INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
> INFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.

And when including models i get following error:

> File "/home/abhishek/FreeLance/Century/centuryApi/centuryApi.py", line 17, in 
> from models.user_master import UserMaster
> File "/home/abhishek/FreeLance/Century/centuryApi/models/user_master.py", line 9, in 
> class UserTypeMaster(db.Model):
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I'm not getting where my reference is wrongly assigned on line 9 in user_master.py

Also i need suggestion regarding this architecture and how can improvise more to make it more scalable.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `@dataclasses` -> `dataclasses is a module, maybe you want `@dataclasses.Dataclass` or similar?

Comment: @snakecharmerb can you also provide some improvisation over this architecture?